# Sorting not working in kotlin by using sortedBy(...)

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

I am  trying to sort this: `listOf("P5","P1","P2","P3","P10")` by using  `val list = categoryList.sortedBy { it }` but what is returning is this: `[P1, P10, P2, P3, P5]` , according to my requirement it should return `[P1, P2, P3, P5, P10]` so what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: your array will be alaways ("P5","P1","P2","P3","P10") ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are sorting `String` list not an `Integer` list. Thats the reason `P10` came in front of `P2`. So, please try below method to sort:

```
 var list: List<String> = mutableListOf("P5","P1","P2","P3","P10")
            .sortedWith(compareBy({ it.length }, { it }))
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how this working? I am not able to understand this expression.

Comment: @sak Here the compareBy is passed with 2 comparators, the length of the string `{ it.length }` and the string value `{ it }`. That ensures that P10 doesn't come just next to P1.

Answer (score 13):

Since you are sorting by string values directly, you are getting that result. Instead, you can sort by the integer part of the strings as below:

```
categoryList.sortedBy { it.substring(1).toInt() }
```

Answer (score 5):

You are sorting strings, not numbers, so Kotlin is sorting them in lexicographical order. That's why "P10" is evaluated as being smaller than "P2".